# Network adapter issue

Tags: networking, windows-server-2016, windows-10, vmware-workstation, ipconfig

I have installed server 2016 in VMware workstation 12 and i am facing some weird issues. I have set my ip address and my default gateway but whenever im trying to run the command ipconfig /release it shows the operation failed as no adaptor is in the state permissible. What to do ?I have tried solving by changing the vmware network settings to default now the ip address os showing only apipa

Answer (score 1):

`ipconfig /release` releases a DHCP-assigned IP address. It doesn't work for manually configured IP addresses which need to be changed manually. If you want to use DHCP you have to configure the NIC to use a dynamically assigned address.

If DHCP doesn't work and falls back to APIPA the connectivity to your DHCP server has failed. You should reconfigure the network in Workstation to bridged. That way, the vNIC looks like a second physical NIC to the network and to the DHCP server.